# calling a function inside another function in a class?

Tags: function, class, python-3.x

I have been trying to call a function inside another function in a class. This resulted in an error. What can I do to fix this.  The code is like:

```
class Goomba:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def goomleft(self,speed):
        for i in range(speed):
            if mask.get_at((self.x,self.y+10))[0] !=255:
                self.x-=1
    def goommove(self,direction):
        if direction == 'left':
            goomleft(self,3)  #this is where I called it
```

The error says
    NameError: global name 'goomleft' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the functions inside of one another because the scope of functions in classes is different:

```
class Goomba:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def goommove(self,direction):
        def goomleft(self,speed):
            for i in range(speed):
                if mask.get_at((self.x,self.y+10))[0] !=255:
                    self.x-=1
        if direction == 'left':
            goomleft(self,3)  #this is where I called it
```

Comment: WAT...  this post gave me cancer.